# Jenkins Pipeline building all branches simultaneously

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I setup a simple Jenkinsfile that just echo a few steps.
I setup a new repo on Bitbucket (git) and two branches called master and develop.

When I commit something to master then both branches checkout and build in jenkins. Same behaviour on the develop branch.

Is it possible to limit only master to build in Jenkins once there is a commit to master branch? Similar behaviour to develop?

Comment: ```if (env.BRANCH == 'master') {
       //do the build
}```

Comment: It seems that is the expected pipeline behaviour but I can't find a document that explains it. I am trying to trigger builds based on tags and regular commits. For example, on master I would like it to build only if a new tag is added.

Comment: @albertjan I have two branches and so, two Jenkinsfile. Would I have to duplicate and specify on each branch. Seems counterintuitive

Comment: Right but branches are usually based on each other, that was my assumption at least. But if you're maintaining them separately, why even add a Jenkinsfile to the non master branch.

Comment: This is the behaviour I would like to have:

Master branch: only build on tag **release-X.Y.Z**
Develop branch: only build on tag **snapshot-X.Y.Z** or **develop branch**

Do I need to have 1 or 2 Jenkinsfile for the pipeline? 
I assume two. One for each branch. Not sure how to limit as shown above.

Comment: Basically, master only builds on a pull request + tag. There is no point on building it every time something is committed to develop branch. Is there an alternative in pipeline to what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a temporary text file to save last successful build SHA ($LAST_SUCCESSFUL_BUILD_SHA) of each branch. Then, when having a new commit from the repo, we'll check which branch the commit comes from.

```
CURRENT_SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

if [ $FORCE_REBUILD = true ] || [ $CURRENT_SHA != $LAST_SUCCESSFUL_BUILD_SHA ]; then
    echo "New commits available OR it was forced to build."
else 
    echo "Already up-to-date. Skip build."
    curl -v -X POST --data "description=no changes, skip." ${JENKINS_BUILD_URL}submitDescription --user <username>:<password>
    curl -v -X POST ${BUILD_URL}stop --user <username>:<password>
    echo "Waiting for abort to take effect :D"
fi
```

If the new commit comes from another branch, it's good to use Jenkins open API to skip the build.

I have applied this for my freestyle jobs but haven't tried with Jenkinsfile.